# Jacobi matrix of birational map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: \mathbb{P^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{P^n}$ be a map $[x_0:\ldots:x_n]\mapsto[f_0(x_0,\ldots,x_n):\ldots: f_n(x_0,\ldots,x_n)]$ (over $\mathbb{C}$), where $f_0,\ldots,f_n$ - homogeneous polynomials of the same degree. Is it true that $f$ is birational map if and only if its jacobian determinant is not everywhere zero?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh $f$ is a rational map.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Do you mean $(x,y,z)\mapsto (yz,xz,xy)$? Its jacobian determinant equals $2xyz\ne 0$. Where's the problem?

Comment: (deleted some mistaken comments...)

Comment: Anyway, I guess the answer is no: for example, the double cover $P^1 \rightarrow P^1$. (I think "generically finite" is true though, at least in char 0.)

Comment: I agree with @AsalBeagDubh. The condition on the jacobian is equivalent to $f$ non-ramified at some point (hence on a dense open subset). This implies that $f$ is generically finite (equivalently $f$ is not dominant by dimension counting). The converse is true in characteristic $0$ because any finite extension of function fields is separable.